# Resizing divs to fit screen vertically and play well with fixed height divs

Tags: css

This might be a basic question, but I've been poking around for help and haven't been able to find a solution.  I have four divs, represented by the areas marked x, a, b, and o.  What I'm trying to achieve is to have **area x and o be of fixed height**, and **areas a and b of variable height to fill up the rest of the screen**.  Is there a pure CSS solution to this problem, or do I need to turn to a JS solution?

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
aaaaaaaaaoooooooooo
aaaaaaaaaoooooooooo
aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[faux(fake) columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)** css technique for A and B. And then place O inside manually and fixed as well as header X. No js needed.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to make two columns equal length regardless of their content, without using tricks like faux columns. +1

Comment: Well I am a bit of oldschool in CSS. So I wasn't sure if there is any new technique for this :) But anyway.. this one is easy and was always working well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this :   position:absolute; and float to where ever you need.

You can also make a table with hidden border, and put your date where ever you want.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the columns will have a fixed height. When the content is longer this fixed height, it doesn't scale.

Comment: Then what about playing with position and floating using css?

Answer (score 0):

one way is to use a mixture of Absolute Positioning, using the four co-ordinates to find the top and bottom of the body , note: needn't be the body, if an element is positioned relatively and has height, AP will find the bottom if it too -

#### see an example in this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/7XBYh/)